# What is the correct way to name a subdomain?

Tags: web, dns, subdomain, multiple-domains

It is about naming URLs, for example `www.example.com/pagename` and `www.pagename.example.com`.

Are they under the same domain name? if so, I don't understand why some websites choose the second option (`www.pagename.example.com`) for some of their pages instead of keep going with the 'normal' way (`www.example.com/pagename`).

Are there any advantage or disadvantages of adding the name at the beginning of the URL?

Comment: There isn't one more "normal" than the other. They have each benefits and drawbacks and then as everything naming related there is a part of subjectivity (many goals could be achieved using either of the two cases).

Comment: What are those advantages and disadvantages? This was the purpose of this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply speaking, `www.pagename.example.com` has subdomains `www`, `pagename` and `example`. There does not appear to be an `index/home` page specified.

`www.example.com/pagename` has subdomains `www`, `exmaple`. It has a page name in this case specified as it is `/` forward slash after top level domain.

In answering your question, well that depends on your needs. If you have separate sites or areas of interest "domains" then you can divy it up but still be under one domain mysite.